# Relative vs absolute address

Tags: excel, vba

I would like my Formula1:="=$J10=""S""" for a relative address instead of an absolute. It must be A10, how do I write it?

```
Sub Makro7()
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A31,B1:B31").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Activate
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$J10=""S"""
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: remove the `$`, which creates a fixed location.

Comment: What's the CF intended to do?  Is it looking at ColJ in the same row for each pair of A,B cells?

Comment: CF is making a boolean value, I can do som conditional formatting on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what the effect of the CF is intended to be, but something like this would work:

```vba
Sub Makro7()

    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveCell.Resize(31, 2)
    rng.Cells(1, 2).Activate
    
    With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                       Formula1:="=" & rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False) & "=""S""")
        .SetFirstPriority
        .StopIfTrue = False
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With 
    End With

End Sub
```